# In MVVMCross 5, how can I navigate backward multiple pages?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In this example, a unique Person is defined by their FirstName and LastName.  `PageA` is a form that selects a unique `Person`. `PageB` is a list of unique FirstNames, and `PageC` is a list of all the LastNames that exist for a given FirstName.

I'm having a hard time solving a particular UX pattern using MvxNavigationService.  Here's what I'm attempting to do, (psuedocode):

- `PageA.SelectedItem = NavigateTo(PageB)` [list of `Person`, grouped
  by `Person.FirstName]`;
- `PageB.SelectedItem = NavigateTo(PageC)` [for
  `Person.FirstName`, list of `Person.LastName`, ];
- `PageC.Close(SelectedItem)`;
- `PageB.Close(SelectedItem)`;

When I actually try and implement this and run it on Android, the viewmodel logic executes, but the UI doesn't show `PageA`.

Update:  Calling `PageB.Close()` navigates back to `PageC`, since `PageC` was the previous page.  Perhaps the problem could be solved by ensuring that `PageC` is removed from the stack upon closing it.  How might this be accomplished?

Comment: Also looking for a solution of programtically removing views from the navigationstack when using the new MvxNavigationService

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways of doing this, using a Custom ViewPresenter on iOS or using an Activity on Android.

One way I achieved this for a small pair (2 view models) was by adding an `Instance` static variable to the first ViewModel that opens the second ViewModel, like this:

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
    public static FirstViewModel Instance;
    public void FirstViewModel()
    {
        Instance = this;
        ...
    }
}
```

And then in the second ViewModel's save/close command, I just closed both ViewModels like this and it worked:

```
public new MvvmCross.Commands.IMvxCommand SaveClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvvmCross.Commands.MvxAsyncCommand(
            async () =>
            {
                await Navigator.Close(this);
                await Navigator.Close(FirstViewModel.Instance);
            }
        );
    }
}
```